# Proof that $\sup(c+A) = c + \sup(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Understanding Analysis: Abbott exercise $1.3.5$:

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be bounded above and let $c \in \mathbb
{R}$. Define the set $c + A = \{c + a : a \in A\} $.

Proof.

Since $A$ is bounded above, there exists an upper bound $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a \le x$, $\forall a \in A$. It follows that $\sup(A) \le x$. Now, $a \le x \implies c+a \le c+x \implies c+a \le c+\sup(A) $. Therefore, $c+\sup(A)$ is an upper bound of $c+A$.

Let x be any upper bound. Since $a \le x \implies a+c \le x+c$, we can call $x+c$ an upper bound of $c+A$ for all $a \in A$. It follows that $c+ \sup(A) \le x+c$ because $\sup(A)\le x$.

Now, because $c+\sup(A)$ is an upper bound of $c+A$ and $c+\sup(A) \le x+c$ which is another upper bound,
$\sup(c+A) = c+\sup(A)$ by definition.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: So far, you showed $\sup(c+A)\le c+\sup(A)$. It is still left to show that $c+\sup(A)\le \sup(c+A)$.

Comment: Use \sup inside $$ to get  healthy $\sup$

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Isn't it enough to show that (i) $c+ \sup(A)$ is an upper bound of $c+A$ and (ii) since $x+c$ is also an upper bound of $c+A$ and $\sup(c+A) \le x+c$?

Comment: @blacknapkins7 You should pull that sentence out into a separate paragraph, and perhaps even prove it. [I am serious.]

Comment: @blacknapkin7   Let $\alpha=\sup A$ . Then $c+a\le c+\alpha\quad,\forall a\in A$ implies $c+\alpha$ is an upper bound of $c+A$ , hence $\sup (c+A) \le c+\alpha$ . __________________________________Let $c+\beta<c+\alpha$ then $\beta<\alpha$ implies $\beta$ can't be an upper bound of $A$ i.e $\exists a_0\in A$ such that $\beta<a_0$ . Then $c+a_0>c+\beta$ implies $c+\beta $ can't be an upper bound of $c+A$ . Hence $c+\alpha$ is the least upper bound of $c+A$ . Done

Comment: For the  second part, it may also run as follows:

If $y$ is an upper bound of $c+A$, then $c+a \le y$ $\forall a \in A$. Hence $a \le y-c$ $\forall a \in A$. Hence $y-c$ is an upper bound of $A$. Thus $\sup A \le y-c$, which implies that $c+\sup A \le y$. This means that any upper bound of $c+A$ is greater than or equal to $c+\sup A$.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung That seems more straightforward; however, is my proof correct?

Comment: @blacknapkin7, You have stated that $ c+\sup A$ is an upper bound of $c+A$ without actually proving it. Though it is obvious, question in this level request unambiguous proof like the first part of what Sourav Ghosh has shown above.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung Edited. How does it look now?

Comment: @blacknapkins7 The first part of your argument contains a logical flaw as follows:

From $\sup A \le x$ and $c+a \le c+x$, it does not follow that  $c+a \le c+\sup A$.

Comment: In the second part of your argument, your have proved that  if $x$ is an upper bound of $A$, then $c+x$ is an upper bound of $c+A$ and conclude that $c+\sup A \le c+x$. But logically this does not imply that $c+\sup A$ is less than or equal to ALL POSSIBLE upper bound unless you have proved that ALL UPPER BOUND MUST BE OF THE FORM $c+x$.  Something is missing here. A more natural approach would be: Let $y$ be any upper bound upper bound of $c+A$ and prove that $y-c$ is an upper bound of $A$.

Comment: To write the proof in your own words Here are some suggestions. 

(1) Take any element $c+a$ of $c+A$, prove that $c+a \le c +\sup A$. ( Sourav Ghosh has done it already .)

(2) Let $y$ be any upper bound of $c+A$, show that $c +\sup A \le y$ (Or as Sourav Ghosh has done, show that any number less than  $c +\sup A$ cannot be an upper bound of $c+A$.)

Comment: @LiKwokKeung I've fixed the 1st and 2nd paragraphs. I am confused why the 2nd is not strong enough. As I understand- since $x$ is an upper bound of $A$, $\sup(A) \le A$. I do not understand why $c+x$ cannot be used, since it is an upper bound of $c+A$ and therefore an upper bound of $A$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138334/discussion-between-li-kwok-keung-and-blacknapkins7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a direct proof:

let $\alpha =\sup A.$ Since $A$ is bounded above, $\alpha\in \mathbb R.$ It is enough to show that $\sup(c+A)=c+\alpha.$

If $a\in A$ then since $a\le \alpha,$ we have $c+a\le c+\alpha$ so

$\tag 1c+\alpha\ \text{is a upper bound for}\ c+A.$

Suppose $\beta $ is another upper bound for $c+A.$ Then, $\beta-c$ is an upper bound for $A$ which means that $\beta-c\ge \alpha$ (since $\alpha = \sup A$). It follows that

$\tag2 \beta\ge c+\alpha.$

To finish, combine $(1)$ and $(2).$

Answer (score 0):

Let $L=\sup(c+A), S=\sup(A), c+A=\{c+a~|~a\in A\}$

First, show $L\le c+S$

$$\forall x\in c+A, \exists a\in A, s.t. x=c+a, \text{and} ~a\le S\Rightarrow x\le c+S\Rightarrow L\le c+S$$

Next, show $L \ge c+S$

Assume the opposite, $L<c+S$, let $\epsilon=\frac{c+S-L}{2}>0$

$$\exists a\in A, s.t. S-a<\epsilon\Rightarrow c+a-L>\epsilon>0\Rightarrow c+a>L$$

Since $c+a\in c+A$, but we get $c+a>L=\sup(c+A)$, which gives a contradiction. Therefore,

$$L\ge c+S$$

Finally, $L=c+S$

Answer (score 0):

We have $x\leq\, supA$ for all $x\in A$ and hence $c+x\,\leq\,c+supA$

for all $x\in A$. That implies that $sup_{A}(c+x)\leq\,c+supA$ and by

definition of the set $c+A$ we obtain: $sup(c+A)\leq\,c+supA$.

Now assume that we have strict inequality. i.e. there is a $\delta$

such that $sup(c+A)\,<\delta\,<\,c+supA$.

Take a sequence $x_{n} \in A$ converging to $supA$.

Then clearly for $n$ sufficiently large $c+x_{n}>\,\delta$.

But $c+x_{n}\,\in \,c+A$ and hence we have an element of $c+A$

greater than the supremum which is an obvious contradiction. Therefore

we have equality and we get our result!